# How can I filter for child properties inside a repeater?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater set to filter based on a few things. I am having issues filtering on child attributes, however. I have a selector populated with category IDs:

```
<select id="searchByCategory" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="categoryFilter">
        <option value="">Filter By Category</option>
        <option value="1">Music</option>
        <option value="4">Sports</option>
        <option value="18">Theater</option>
        <option value="19">Exhibit/Class</option>
        <option value="21">Other</option>
</select>
```

And the repeater:

```
<div class="row tableCell" ng-repeat="event in events | filter: { DateBegin: DateBegin } | filter: search | filter: { Category.ID: categoryFilter }">
        <h2 ng-show="$first">{{ event.DateBegin | date:'MMMM d, yyyy' }}</h2><br />
        <a href="/EventDetails/{{ event.ID }}"><h1>{{ event.Name }}</h1></a>
        <p>{{ event.Description }}</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Category ID: {{ event.Category.ID }}</li>
            <li>Category Name: {{ event.Category.Name }}</li>
            <li>Time Begin: {{ event.TimeBegin }}</li>
            <li>Duration: {{ event.Duration }}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I know that Category.ID and Category.Name are working because they are displayed inside the event details. However, as soon as I try selecting a category from the dropdown menu, no events are displayed. What's wrong with my filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
filter: { Category.ID: categoryFilter }
```

to

```
filter: { Category: categoryFilter }
```

I made a demo here on this plunkr, try to change the select option ( which seems like ur case )

http://plnkr.co/edit/vEVBEcnx3FLvXGJaElT3?p=preview

( this plnkr is an edited from a demo on  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter )